# Order indicator progress animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml, android-progressbar, indicator

I'm working on order progress indicator thing. It's just order progress after user place an order and they can track their order id by open this app.

Below is the example indicator progress animation I want to build in my order app.

[image: Example of order progress image jpg]

Is there any library to create this kind of animation in android. Is it possible to create just using bunch of images (blue,red,grey) drag drop align in relative layout? If can.. it maybe a lot of code and just to align those images.

Blue - in-progress
Red - in working (blinking animation) 
Grey - done

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: looks like you have to implement one yourself or use a pi chart from any graph-chart library.

Comment: well you can do that, use framelayout and single 1/8 of the full round imageview (i mean one part). All you need is 8*3=24 images. use some animation